# Backbone Model caching and fetching locally

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, highcharts

I have been working on a dashboard with backbone and highcharts. I am using a backend MySql server which has all the data I need to chart different things on the front end.

The pattern we are trying to follow here is that I will have a Backbone model on which I can do a `fetch`, which will accept in the `data` object `dateStart` and `dateEnd` and get the entire data blob.

Now, once I get the data blob back from the server I want to be able to cache it locally and regraph different things based on different filters using Highcharts. A sample data blob is as below. The server returns an array of objects.

```
{
    "dt": "2015-11-02",
    "ad_product": "product name",
    "environment": "mobile",
    "geo_code": "country name",
    "unique_users": "1",
    "impressions": "1",
    "all_engagements": "1"
  }
```

The user will be able to select different filters like `ad_product`, `geo_code`, `metric` and `environment` on the front end and based on that I want to be able to query this backbone model data with those filters and generate the `series` array and feed it to the backbone view which has highcharts.

Is there a good way to do this? I could not find anything good on here which would allow me to do this in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a backbone model is to store data for you. Here is an example of how you might want to structure your code:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var model = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/my-api-endpoint'
        }).then(function(data) {
            model.set(data);
            model.trigger('data:loaded');
        }).fail(function() {
            model.trigger('data:error');
        });
    }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var view = this;

        this.model.on('data:error', function() {
            console.log('there was an error getting data');
        }).on('data:loaded', function() {
            view.render();
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.renderHighcharts();
    },
    renderHighcharts: function(data) {
        data = data || this.model.toJSON();
        $('#highchart-container').highcharts({
            // highcharts stuff here
        });
    },
    events: function() {
        'change .filter.geo_code': function(e) {
            var geoCode = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
                data = this.model.toJSON()
            ;
            data = data.filter(function(dataPoint) {
                return dataPoint.geoCode == geoCode;
            });
            view.renderHighcharts(data);
        }
    }
});

new MyView({
    el: '#main',
    model: new MyModel
});
```